# Output for making and checking no's of 5's,3's or combination of both not getting as expected?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve the question given [in this link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-the-beast).

I am able to solve the no's of 5,no's of 3 but not combination of both.

makeDigit make the no of 5's,3's and combination of both.

checkDigit return the combination depending upon which is greater.

What I am doing wrong?

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++)
    {
        int n = in.nextInt();
         StringBuffer s1=makeDigits(n);
         System.out.println(s1);

    }
    in.close();
 }

public static StringBuffer makeDigits(int p)
    {
         int count3=0;
         int count5=0;
          int count53=0;
         StringBuffer str5=new StringBuffer();
         StringBuffer str3=new StringBuffer();
         StringBuffer str53=new StringBuffer();
         for(int a1=0;a1<p;a1++)
             {
                 str5=str5.append("5");
                 count5++;
             }
         for(int a2=0;a2<p;a2++)
             {
                 str3.append("3");
                 count3++;
             }
         for(int a5=0;;a5++)
             {

                 str53.append("5");

                 if(a5%3==0)
                 {
                     break;
                 }

             }
         for(int a6=0;;a6++)
         {
             str53.append("3");
             if(a6%5==0)
             {
                 break;
             }

         }

 StringBuffer  s2=checkDigits(str5,count5,str3,count3,str53,count53);

 return s2;

    }
public static StringBuffer checkDigits(StringBuffer strnew5,int c5,StringBuffer strnew3,int c3,StringBuffer strnew53,int c53)

 {
              boolean b5=false;
              boolean b3=false;
              boolean b53=false;
              StringBuffer strnew=new StringBuffer(); 
              if(c5%3==0)
              {
               b5=true;
              }
            else if(c5%3==0&&c3%5==0)
               {
                 b53=true;

               }

               else if(c3%5==0)
               {
                 b3=true;

               }


                if(b5==true)
                    return strnew5;
                else if(b53==true)

                    return strnew53;

                else if(b3==true)

                    return strnew3;

                else
                    return strnew.append("-1");

           }
}

Input (stdin)

4
1
3
5
11

Your Output (stdout)

-1
555
33333
-1

Expected Output

-1
555
33333
55555533333
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html), use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). See javadoc of `StringBuffer` for why.

Better yet, use a `char[]` and [`Arrays.fill()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28char[],%20int,%20int,%20char%29).

---

You need to calculate the best solution, i.e.

```
A * 3 + B * 5 = N
```

where `A` is an integer representing the number of 5's, and `B` is an integer representing the number of 3's.

The goal is to find the smallest `B`, where `A` is an integer, which means that `B` should be 0, 1, or 2. I'll leave it to you to figure out why that is.

The largest result is `A` 5's followed by `B` 3's.

Good luck!

---

Just for the heck of it, here is a condensed version. *Don't use it unless you understand it!*

```
private static String findLargestDecentNumber(int n) {
    int i = n - (3 - n % 3) % 3 * 5;
    if (n <= 0 || i < 0)
        return "-1";
    char[] buf = new char[n];
    Arrays.fill(buf, 0, i, '5');
    Arrays.fill(buf, i, n, '3');
    return new String(buf);
}
```